# Filtrar un objeto dependiendo de un rango elegido por el usuario

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Estoy haciendo un programa en React, en donde el usuario puede elegir distintos parámetros, uno de ellos es entre que fechas quiere que se muestre la información. Mi objeto es el siguiente:

```
let data = {
      "1960": "30",
      "1961": "25",
      "1962": "50",
      "1963": "25",
      "1964": "45",
      "1965": "67",
      "1966": "22",
      "1967": "5",
      "1968": "15",
      "1969": "25",
      "1970": "11",
      "1971": "54",
      "1972": "11",
      "1973": "22",
      "1974": "35",
      "1975": "40" }
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que se muestre la información entre un rango de fechas? Por ejemplo, si el usuario elige como startDate 1960 y endDate 1968 que sólo se muestre la información en ese rango.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con lo siguiente:

```js
let data = {
  '1960': '30',
  '1961': '25',
  '1962': '50',
  '1963': '25',
  '1964': '45',
  '1965': '67',
  '1966': '22',
  '1967': '5',
  '1968': '15',
  '1969': '25',
  '1970': '11',
  '1971': '54',
  '1972': '11',
  '1973': '22',
  '1974': '35',
  '1975': '40',
};
// Simulando input del usuario
const startDate = 1960;
const endDate = 1968;
// Primero obtienes los keys de tu objeto
const results = Object.keys(data)
  // luego filtras esos keys bajo las condiciones que necesites
  .filter((key) => parseInt(key) >= startDate && parseInt(key) <= endDate)
  // para finalmente regenerar el objeto basado en los keys previamente filtrados
  .map((key) => ({ [key]: data[key] }));
console.log(results);
```